# How to C++ compile staticly thired party library which contains another library that others are using in main app

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries

i have 2 OSS thired party librarys which all are using another thired party library all compiles as STATIC.
For the sake of context what i have:
static libssh -> using static openssl lib
static libcurl -> using static openssl lib
My main app that is using openssl static 
Now i compile libssh and libcurl as static libs speratly they all compile with static version of openssl
As i understand now libcurl and libssh contains the static links openssl
If its true i have 2 openssl embedded in libssh and libcurl which embeddedalso in to my app plus another one that my own main app is using .
My question is how to compile statically the third party libraries but make them use 1 copy of static openssl ?
I don't want to import libssh  libcurl source code into my app but link them statically as separate lib files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static library is really only an archive (that's the reason for the `.a` suffix) of object files. They most certainly don't contain any of their dependencies as they are not really linked when being created.

If you use static libraries, then you explicitly need to link with all the libraries dependencies as well.

Comment: If i understand you right the actual (in my case) static openssl library 
will only be finally linked and used in my main app?